# Dropping duplicates based on mode and highest value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem regarding dropping duplicates. The setting is this: I have number of apartments from different dates as a series. I want to drop all previous information about apartments that occur in the data again with higher date value. Now let's say that with date value 1.1.2000 there are 3 apartments in the data and with date value 1.1.2001 there are 2 apartments in the data. The result dataframe should have one apartment from the 1.1.2000 and two apartments from 1.1.2001. However, if there are 2 apartments with date value 1.1.2000 and 3 apartments with date value 1.1.2001, in the result dataframe there should be only the three apartments from 1.1.2001

Example of the data and the result

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'city' : ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'Boston', 
'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston'],
'rooms': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5], 'floor': [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9], 
'date': 
['1.1.2020', '1.1.2020', '1.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '1.1.2020', '1.1.2020', 
'15.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '19.1.2020',  '22.1.2020'],
'rent' : [100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

result = {'city' : ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston'],
'rooms': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], 'floor': [1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 9], 'date': 
['1.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '15.1.2020', '19.1.2020',  '22.1.2020'],
'rent' : [100, 130, 140, 170, 190, 200]}
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data = result)
result_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['date'])
```

I tried something like this, but it does not find the mode with highest date value and it is still missing the part where the old data is replaced with the newer

```
s = df1.groupby(['city', 'rooms', 'floor']).date.agg(lambda x : x.mode()[0]).reset_index()
result_df2 = s.merge(df1, how = "left", on = ['city', 'rooms', 'floor', 'date'])
```